# Is 君の腕に期待する a set phrase that has to do with 'skill'?

Tags: meaning, words

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2h-oI7NsS_8&t=2m21s

> フォックス機の操縦桿を握る、君の腕に期待するぜ。

*I'm looking forward to your arm holding the control stick of the Fox aircraft.*

or if it means skill, then that would change the meaning completely:

*We hope you'll be able to maneuver the aircraft. We're counting on you!*

Answer (score 2):

Yes. In this case, 腕 itself means skill.
You can also think that it's got shortened from "腕前", which also means skill / talent.

"前" in this case is suffix that emphasize the previous word. e.g. 男前:handsome man.

Similar words are "手腕", "手並み" - which also means skill / talent.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Maybe it's something like: "We hope you'll be able to skillfully maneuver the aircraft. We're counting on you!

Comment: I'd translate it to "We look forward to seeing your skills at the controls of Fox's aircraft. We're counting on you!" since original sentence specifies that it's Fox's aircraft(I know nothing about Starfox so I don't know if it's a person or name of squadron, but still.).