# Help understand 俺の腕前がわかったろう。

Tags: meaning

Veterans, please help me understand the following sentence. You can help me by either explaining grammar or providing an accurate and literate translation in English. If you need context information, please let me know.
俺の腕前がわかったろう。

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [We don't do translations](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/799/1628).

Comment: Is there a specific word or construction that you are struggling with?  If you provide your own attempt at translation, we can help you better.  Otherwise, this thread will probably be closed.

Comment: Not a veteran by all means here, but here's a friendly reference: [腕](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/87254/) and [たろう](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/73600/is-short-past-%e3%82%8d%e3%81%86-like-%e3%81%a0%e3%82%8d%e3%81%86) - I hope this helps improve your Japanese 腕前

Answer (score 3):

質問者様が何かの本か漫画などでこのフレーズを読み質問したのだと仮定して、回答させていただきます。

一般的に日本語で「腕前」と言う意味はその人の力量を表すものであり、その人の技量、強さ、熟練度などを表す単語として使われることが多いです。

ですので漫画などでも、そのキャラクターの「腕前」、敵の「腕前」のように相手の強さを表すスラングとして使われています。

今回の質問である「俺の腕前がわかったろう。」と言う文章でも、何かの人物が自分の技力を見せつけ吐き捨てるときに使われたものだと推測します。

**例文：**

・彼の剣道の腕前は日本一だ。

・彼女の武道の腕前は強い。

・このチームの腕前は世界でも上位を争う